# How can I create and pass a null-terminated array of C-strings (char**) in rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, c-str

I'm playing around with a new init system with `#![no_std]` and `extern crate rlibc` and making syscalls with asm, and currently trying to not allocate memory either.  So the scope of possible tools I have is limited.

I need to call the execve syscall, and it requires a `char** argv`, and a `char **envp`.  I can hack together c-style strings as arrays of bytes with zeros, *but how can I null-terminate a statically declared list of such (the last pointer being NULL)*?

Answer (score 7):

After sleeping on this, I woke up with the answer, and it seems obvious to me now.  Use slices of integers and set the last one to 0.

```
// Execute something as an example:
let filename: &[u8] = b"/usr/bin/sensors\x00";     // <-- Make c strings like this
let argv1: &[u8] = b"/usr/bin/sensors\x00";
let argv2: &[u8] = b"-h\x00";
let argv: &[int] = [                               // <-- store them in this
    ::core::intrinsics::transmute(argv1.as_ptr()), // <-- transmuting 
    ::core::intrinsics::transmute(argv2.as_ptr()),
    0                                              // <-- and NULL terminate
];
let envp: &[int] = [0];

::linux64::execve(filename,argv,envp);
```

Comment: You should use `*const u8` instead of `int`. The `as_ptr()` method already returns a `*const u8`, so you can just remove the `transmute`. To get a null pointer, use `ptr::null()` (or `0 as *const T`) instead of `0`.

Comment: Also, you can use `\0` instead of `\x00` in bytestrings to represent a null byte.

Comment: You can cast raw pointers to and from integers freely (`argv1.as_ptr() as int`), but as @FrancisGagné, suggests, it would be better to store a `&[*const u8]`. Also, do you know about `use`, while allows to to bring names into scope, e.g. `use core::mem; ... mem::transmute(...)`?

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Thanks for that I was hoping someone would comment on the types

Comment: @dbaupp I didn't know the cast was so easy.  Yes I know about use, I prefer to see the full paths for the moment.